# WebDAV Slide Subscription - Get changes

Tags: java, notifications, webdav, slide

how to use the subscription-Method in "org.apache.webdav.lib.WebdavResource" ? In version 2.1 of the jakarta slide-Project there is a new Method "subscribeMethod". I can't find any examples for it. I want to get a notification, when a file on the WebDAV-Server has changed, deleted or is new. Is this possible with a subscription?

Currently I'm checking all files on the web-dav server, put them in some vectors and check them again every 5 seconds. But on a webdav-system with more than 150 folders and lots of files, it takes up to 5 minutes to scan all files and then comparing it with the old situation.

Is there a better and faster way to get the changes instantly?

Answer (score 0):

Highly depends on the server your using. There's a WebDAV sync spec that solves your problem, but I'm not aware of any server implementations.

The most you can do with a 'plain' WebDAV server is fetch and compare the ETag with PROPFIND.